# Why the grid scores from RFECV using ROC AUC is different from ROC AUC obtained by the same selected features?

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn

I'm using RFECV with the scoring ROC AUC for feature selection and the model selected 3 features. However, when use these 3 features with the same estimator and same cross validation when I run the RFECV, the ROC AUC values are different.
And I also tried to use the example RFECV implementation from sklearn documentation and I also found the same problem. In the RFECV the grid scores when using 3 features is [0.99968  0.991984] but when I use the same 3 features to calculate a seperate ROC-AUC, the results are [0.999584 0.99096]. But when I change the scoring method to 'accuracy' everything is the same.

```
X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=1000,
    n_features=25,
    n_informative=3,
    n_redundant=2,
    n_repeated=0,
    n_classes=8,
    n_clusters_per_class=1,
    random_state=0,
)

svc = SVC(kernel="linear")
cv = StratifiedKFold(2, random_state = 0, shuffle =True)
min_features_to_select = 1  # Minimum number of features to consider
rfecv = RFECV(
    estimator=svc,
    step=1,
    cv=cv,
    scoring="accuracy",
    min_features_to_select=min_features_to_select,
)
rfecv.fit(X, y)

selected_features = (X[:,rfecv.get_support()])

cv_score = cross_val_score(svc, selected_features, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv =cv)
```

Can someone help me to explain this phenomenon?
Thank you so much